# Content within DIV areas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FyjAh/) and would like to place some content within each of the different coloured `#div` sections.

However, when I try to do so, the information exceeds passed the allocated space, as seen in this  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt9Cz/).

How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove this css attribute:

```
 white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: If I remove that line from the CSS, the page no longer becomes a side-scrolling website.

Comment: then you will need to add a specific overwriting CSS attribute to the container slide divs:

ie:

    `.slide_div_class {
        white-space: normal
    }`

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you please provide this in a working jsfiddle example Jonathan?

Comment: Everything seems to drop when viewing the different areas in your example Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

**This is because you are using `white-space: nowrap;` that means:**

Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a `<br />` tag is encountered
so kindly remove it from your css code

here is the link to understand `white-space property`

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Comment: If I remove that line from the CSS, the page no longer becomes a side-scrolling website.